# Where should I place the validationSchema?

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, yup, web-frontend

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, validateYupSchema } from "formik";
import { FC } from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";
 
interface inputProps {
name : string,
type? : string,
label : string,
labelClassname? :string,
inputClassname? : string,
errorClassname? : string
}
 
const Input : FC<inputProps> = ({
      name,
      type = 'text',
      label,
      labelClassname,
      inputClassname,
      errorClassname             
}) => {
      return(
          <>
              <label htmlFor={name} className={`block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 ${labelClassname ?? ''}`}>
                {label}
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <Field id={name} name={name} type={type} autoComplete="name" className={`block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6 ${inputClassname ?? ''}`} />
              </div>
          <ErrorMessage name={name} className={`text-red-500 text-sm ${errorClassname ?? ''}`} component="div" />
          </> 
 
          validationSchema:registerValidationSchema; 
      )  
 
}
 
const registerValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
      name :yup.string().required().min(2),
      email : yup.string().required().email(),
      password :yup.string().required().min(4)              
})               
 
export default Input;
```

I want to do validation through schema validation for the registration form.

It shows a Unreachable error in Vs Code.

Where should I put the validationSchema so that it doesn't make an error?

Hello, where should I put the schema validation? I have been asked where I should put it, not just this project in general